# cakephp contain

Tags: cakephp, containable, contain

I have a problem with contain :( , let me explain:

Models Relations:

Client -> hasMany -> Card -> hasAndBelongsToMany -> Partner -> hasMany -> Contact

What i need is to get all partners and contacts of Client with codigo = 24150 and Contacts with coords_lat = 38.71093.

Code:

```
$conditions = array('conditions' => 
   array('codigo' => '24150')
);

$contain = array(
   'contain'=> array(
    'Partner' => array(
       'Contact' => array('conditions' => array('coords_lat' => '38.71093')) 
    )
   )
);

$parceiros = $this->Client->find('all', array($conditions, $contain));
```

I've added

```
var $actsAs = array('Containable');
```

to app_model.php

To be totally honest with you, i don't really understand what is happening here... truth is that mysql does huge queries and takes tons of time but i don't see it selecting by "codigo = 24150"

I would appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Rui

Comment: What is the output you're getting right now? What's the content of `$parceiros`?

Comment: I think you should check @Leo's answer. That's probably where you go wrong. Your syntax looks okay.

Comment: No output... because cakephp generates crazy queries, please check here:
http://pastebin.me/24d7e33ce334e56087dcb657080325ce

Im sorry for the name of the tables, they are in portuguese Cliente = Cliente, CgdCartoesCliente = Card, cgd_cartoes_clientes = HATBM connection table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally fixed it, cakephp didn't like having conditions and contain in different arrays. The solution for this is:

```
$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array('codigo' => '24150'),
    'contain' => array(
        'Card'=>array(
            'Partner' => array (
                'Contact' => array(
                    'conditions' => array('Contact.coords_lat' => '38.710930')
                 )
             )
         )
     )
 );

 $parceiros = $this->Client->find('all', $conditions);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also keep both of your arrays `$conditions` and `$contain` separated..

and change the last line to be:

```
$parceiros = $this->Client->find('all', array_merge($conditions, $contain));
```

notice the array_merge function..
this should fix your problem without needing to use only one array for both of them

Answer (score 1):

You should be getting an error stating that Client is not related to Partner. Try the following

```
$this->Client->contain(
    'Card'=>array('Partner' => array(
       'Contact' => array('conditions' => array('coords_lat' => '38.71093')) 
    )
   )
)
);

$parceiros = $this->Client->find('all', array('conditions' => 
                                            array('Client.codigo' => '24150')
                                            )
                                  )
```

Comment: No luck.... still generates long queries and mysql timesout :( also i don't see it selecting by codigo 24150. Please check the queries here:
http://pastebin.me/24d7e33ce334e56087dcb657080325ce

Comment: OK Rui lets try a little process of elimination. Comment out the $this->Client->contain line. Then pr() the contents of $parceiros, what do you get?

Comment: Something is strange, apparently $conditions is ignored in the find :( I did add recursive = -1 and query generated is "select * from clientes WHERE 1 = 1" ? :(

Comment: So did it return all the Clients? execute just the last line again ( I have amended it to include the model name )

Comment: It's getting better now.... Returned the Client and the Cards... but didn't return Partners and Contacts. (I did uncomment the contain line)

Comment: Right we're going round in circles now.

Executing JUST the last line do you get the Client(s) returned with a 'codigo' of 24150

Comment: Leo, yes.... and with cards too. It returns the Client with codigo 24150 and his cards (which are IDs 14,23,29)...

Comment: Ok if you're not getting anything with the contain uncommented you.may have an issue.with your relationships. Set recursive to 2 and what do you get?

Comment: I tried setting recursive to 5... and i get all the relationships fine... when i add contain, it stops working... also 'conditions' => array('coords_lat' => '38.71093') seems to be ignored.

Comment: tried to simplify contain to:
$this->Client->contain = array(       'Card'=>array('Partner'));
but doesn't work too :(

Comment: No worries, I stupidldy was assigning an array to $this->client->contain which is obviously a method. I have re-edited my code